# How to set the default libraries when doing unit tests under Python 2.7

Tags: unit-testing, google-app-engine, python-2.7

I'm in the process of migrating my Google AppEngine solution from Python 2.5 to 2.7. The application migration was relatively easy, but I'm struggling with the unittests.

In the 2.5 version I was using the use_library function to set the django version to 1.2, but this isn't supported anymore on 2.7. Now I set the default version in the app.yaml.

When I'm now running my unittests the default django version becomes 0.96 and I can't manage to set the 1.2 as the default version.

Who knows how I can set the default libraries for the unittest, so the match the settings in the app.yaml?

Comment: Did you get a solution? I now that your problem was a lot time ago but I have the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

Use the following syntax in `app.yaml` to set the Django version used throughout:

```
libraries:
- name: django
  version: "1.3"
```

More details on how to set up use of 3rd party libraries in Python 2.7 [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27).

Comment: I've done what you said and it works fine when running the application on dev server and production. However when I run unit test this app.yaml configuration is nog read and I get the default 0.96 version

Comment: @aadjemonkeyrock Ah, check where Django is being imported from by first `import django` and then `django.__file__`. Recall that when running tests you are not running in the GAE environment, but using your own box's config.

Comment: This does not work for me when running unit tests.
Also use_library does not work because for some reason, when running from unittests then max avail django version is 1.3 (seems to be last available in python 2.5), while I need Django 1.5

Comment: @Alex-OffiServ Can't really help you as I have not worked with GAE for a while now. If you manage to find a solution please post a comment and/or edit.

Answer (score 0):

`app.yaml` configuration is not applied when doing unit tests with webtest app and NoseGAE.
`use_library` does not work neither.

The right solution for this case is to provide proper python path to the preferred lib version, e.g. `PYTHONPATH=../google_appengine/lib/django-1.5` when running nosetests.